# How to create SignalHub in a QT application?

Tags: linux, qt5

There is a multi-threaded application on QT5. Threads emits signals to each other. For example, the button click signal in the GUI comes in three separate threads, and each thread performs its own function. Is there an easy way to connect all signals to some object, let's call it SignalHub? And this SignalHub will receive all signals from all threads or objects, and any thread or object can be subscribed to the desired signal? Something similar to DBus, but only for several threads within a single QT application? Each thread or object should not receive its own signal. The purpose of this is to reduce the amount of code (there are several threads in the application, and each has multiple signals and slots). And it would be ideal to connect the necessary signals to (and from) the SignalHub only in new object's constructor or new thread's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Signals are thread-safe. So are connect() and disconnect(). Meaning: you can literally declare any object you want to be your "signal hub" and just connect the slots across threads as you desire. To what threads the objects involved belong doesn't matter. No problems.

To avoid receiving signals an object sent itself, you can simply do something along those lines:

```cpp
void MyObject::someSlot() {
  if(sender() == this) return;
}
```